# PL/SQL DBMS_DATAPUMP ERROR ORA-39109 Even with EXP_FULL_DATABASE role set

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, datapump

I'm using a PL/SQL procedure to save, using datapump, old data in some tables on different schemas.
I'm trying to centralize everything on a management schema.
Everything works fine while in the same schema (eg. HR) but the procedure raises an ORA-39109 error when it tries to export tables on other schemas.
As SYS I've set EXP_FULL_DATABASE role and explicitly set CREATE TABLE privilege without luck.
I've also set all privileges under EXP_FULL_DATABASE role but still no success.

This is the stored procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE exp_tables_w_qfilter
(
 p_schema_name IN VARCHAR2,              -- schema name
 p_table_name IN VARCHAR2,               -- source tables
 p_table_filter IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL -- table predicate to filter data (where clause)
)
    IS
        v_sid VARCHAR2(200) := 'DB11G';                -- sid for this database
        v_handle NUMBER;                               -- job handle
        v_current_time DATE := SYSDATE;                -- consistent timestamp for files, job_name etc.
        v_start_time DATE;                             -- start time for log file
        v_logfile_name VARCHAR2(200);                  -- logfile name
        v_dumpfile_name VARCHAR2(200);                 -- logfile name
        v_default_dir VARCHAR(30) := 'DATA_PUMP_DIR';  -- directory
        v_line_no INTEGER := 0;                        -- debug line no
        v_sqlcode NUMBER;                              -- sqlcode
        v_compatible VARCHAR2(40) := 'COMPATIBLE';     -- default is 'COMPATIBLE'
        vc_job_mode CONSTANT VARCHAR2(200) := 'TABLE'; -- Job mode

    BEGIN

        v_line_no := 100; -- debug line no

        -- Ceate the log and dumpfile names
        IF v_compatible = 'COMPATIBLE'
        THEN
            v_logfile_name := 'expdp_' || v_sid || '_' || p_table_name || '_' || TO_CHAR(v_current_time, 'YYYY_MMDD_HH24MI') || '.log';
            v_dumpfile_name := 'expdp_' || v_sid || '_%U_' || p_table_name || '_' || TO_CHAR(v_current_time, 'YYYY_MMDD_HH24MI') || '.dmp';
        ELSE
            v_logfile_name := 'expdp_' || v_sid || '_' || p_table_name || '_' || TO_CHAR(v_current_time, 'YYYY_MMDD_HH24MI') || '_' || v_compatible || '.log';
            v_dumpfile_name := 'expdp_' || v_sid || '_%U_' || p_table_name || '_' || TO_CHAR(v_current_time, 'YYYY_MMDD_HH24MI') || '_' || v_compatible || '.dmp';
        END IF;

        v_line_no := 150; -- debug line no

        -- Open the job
        BEGIN
            v_handle :=
                DBMS_DATAPUMP.open(operation => 'EXPORT',
                                   job_mode => vc_job_mode,
                                   job_name => 'EXPORT_' || vc_job_mode || '_' || p_table_name || '_' || TO_CHAR(v_current_time, 'YYYY_MMDD_HH24MI'),
                                   version => v_compatible);
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS
            THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(SUBSTR('Failure in dbms_datapump.open', 1, 255));
                RAISE;
        END;

        v_line_no := 200; -- debug line no


        -- Add a logfile
        DBMS_DATAPUMP.add_file(handle => v_handle,
                               filename => v_logfile_name,
                               directory => v_default_dir,
                               filetype => DBMS_DATAPUMP.ku$_file_type_log_file);

        v_line_no := 400; -- debug line no

        -- Add a datafile
        DBMS_DATAPUMP.add_file(handle => v_handle,
                               filename => 'dp' || '_%U_' || v_dumpfile_name,
                               directory => v_default_dir,
                               filetype => DBMS_DATAPUMP.ku$_file_type_dump_file);

         v_line_no := 500; -- debug line no

        -- Filter for the schema
        DBMS_DATAPUMP.metadata_filter(handle => v_handle, name => 'SCHEMA_LIST', VALUE => '''' || p_schema_name || '''');

        v_line_no := 550; -- debug line no

        -- Filter for the table
        DBMS_DATAPUMP.metadata_filter(handle => v_handle, name => 'NAME_LIST', VALUE => '''' || p_table_name || '''');

        v_line_no := 570; -- debug line no

        -- Add a subquery
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('SCHEMA....:'||p_schema_name);                                  
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('TABLE.....:'||p_table_name);                                  
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('FILTER....:'||p_table_filter);                                  

        DBMS_DATAPUMP.data_filter(handle => v_handle, name => 'SUBQUERY', VALUE => p_table_filter);

        v_line_no := 600; -- debug line no

        -- Get the start time
        v_start_time := SYSDATE;

        -- Add a start time to the log file
        DBMS_DATAPUMP.log_entry(handle => v_handle, MESSAGE => 'Job Start at ' || TO_CHAR(v_start_time, 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS'), log_file_only => 0);

        v_line_no := 700; -- debug line no

        -- Start the job
        DBMS_DATAPUMP.start_job(handle => v_handle);
        DBMS_DATAPUMP.detach(handle => v_handle);

        v_line_no := 800; -- debug line no

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS
        THEN

            BEGIN
                DBMS_DATAPUMP.detach(handle => v_handle);
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN OTHERS
                THEN
                    NULL;
            END;

            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(SUBSTR('Value of v_line_no=' || TO_CHAR(v_line_no), 1, 255));
            RAISE;

    END exp_tables_w_qfilter; -- Procedure exp_tables_w_qfilter
```

Those are the grants I gave to my management schema

```
create session, 
create table, 
create procedure, 
datapump_exp_full_database, 
exp_full_database,
datapump_imp_full_database, 
imp_full_database
```

Those are the privileges under EXP_FULL_DATABASE role i explicitly gave to the management user

```
READ ANY FILE GROUP
     ,RESUMABLE
     ,EXECUTE ANY PROCEDURE
     ,EXECUTE ANY TYPE
     ,SELECT ANY TABLE
     ,ADMINISTER SQL MANAGEMENT OBJECT
     ,ADMINISTER RESOURCE MANAGER
     ,BACKUP ANY TABLE
     ,CREATE SESSION
     ,SELECT ANY SEQUENCE
     ,CREATE TABLE
```

I run the procedure with;

```
DECLARE 

   CURSOR c_dp_tables is 
    SELECT owner, 
           tbname, 
           tsfield, 
           m2keep 
      FROM dp_tables; 
   v_history number; 
   v_query varchar(255);
   v_field varchar(35);

BEGIN 

  FOR dptbl_rec IN c_dp_tables LOOP 
    v_history := dptbl_rec.m2keep; 
      v_field   := dptbl_rec.tsfield;
      v_query   := 'where '||v_field || ' < add_months(sysdate, -'||v_history||')';
    exp_tables_w_qfilter(dptbl_rec.owner, dptbl_rec.tbname, v_query); 


  END LOOP; 

 END;
```

The Output is

```
Report error -
ORA-31631: sono necessari appositi privilegi
ORA-06512: a "HR.EXP_TABLES_W_QFILTER", line 117
ORA-06512: a line 19
31631. 00000 -  "privileges are required" 
*Cause:    The necessary privileges are not available for operations such
           as: restarting a job on behalf of another owner, using a device
           as a member of the dump file set, or ommiting a directory
           object associated with any of the various output files.
           Refer to any following error messages for additional information.
*Action:   Select a different job to restart, try a different operation, or
           contact a database administrator to acquire the needed privileges.
```

In the DATA_PUMP_DIR I can find the log file saying:

```
$ more expdp_DB11G_ACCOUNT_ANALYTIC_LINE_2017_0614_1214.log
ORA-39109: Gli utenti privi di privilegi non possono utilizzare gli schemi degli altri utenti
ORA-39012: Client scollegato prima dell'avvio del job.
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Please update your question to include the full error message. I don't know about you, but I'm not a walking encyclopaedia of Oracle error messages and their codes! *{;-)

Comment: Done and sorry for the headache ;)